# Where to add event tracking code for a button?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, dom-events

I'm wondering where to add event tracking code for a button click on our top navigation tab that takes you from the homepage to a subdomain of the site.

This is the code I have now:

```
onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'top_nav_tab' , 'click' , 'chickenwins_mar17' );
```

I want to put it on this site: http://inghams.co.nz/ adding it to the "Red Box Promotion" tab, so I was thinking of adding it to the item `li id="menu-item-1650"`, so it would look like:

```
<li id="menu-item-1650" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'top_nav_tab' , 'click' , 'chickenwins_mar17' );" class=class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1650">
```

But I don't think that's working. Any suggestions? I know how to add button tracking via custom JavaScript variable in GTM but we aren't using GTM on this site.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it and I think you are looking for this:(The onclick event is inside the list tag's anchor tag)

```
<li id="menu-item-1650" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1650"><a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'top_nav_tab' , 'click' , 'chickenwins_mar17' );" href="http://chickenwins.inghams.co.nz">Red Box Promotion</a></li>
```

I have made that with a screenshot so you can implement it [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/egx8ldx559ne2pm/OnPaste.20170327-075206.png?dl=0)

Comment: Thank you! I am trying that right now and will test with GA to see if it works. But I think you're right I needed to nest it further in the menu item object. Thanks so much! :)

Comment: My pleasure, if it is ok with you please accept the answer or comment with anything you need